# Admin order new email template override?

Tags: magento2

I want to override admin invoice email template in my custom module but I have no idea for this please suggest me if anyone did this task.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find out your answer in [Customize email templates](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html)